# How to properly organise the database calls with Python and MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a code like this:

```py
import mysql.connector as mysql
from generate_records import generateRecords

devicesQuery = "CALL iot.sp_sensors_overview()"

try:
    db = mysql.connect(
        user = "username", 
        password = "password", 
        host = "hostname",
        database="iot"
    )

    cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True)
    cursor.execute(devicesQuery)

    for sensor in cursor:
        generateRecords(sensor, db)
    
    cursor.close()
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Error:")
    print(error)
else:
    db.close()
```

The purpose of `generateRecords` function is obviously to generate records and run the INSERT query against the different table.

Seems like I do something wrong, because no matter what I trying, I getting different errors here, like `mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.`.

(upd) I also tried to change the code like it was suggested (see example bellow), with no luck - I still receiving the `MySQL connection not available.` error.

```py
rows = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()

for sensor in rows:
     cursor2 = db.cursor()
     generateRecords(sensor, cursor2)
```

So, should I create a new connection within `generateRecords` function, or pass something different within it, or use some kind of different approach here?

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you get those errors?  Does `generateRecords` create its own cursor?  Remember that you're in the middle of a query here.  You might consider fetching all of the records into a list, then closing the cursor, then running your `generateRecords` loop.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, `generateRecords` creates a cursor and at this point it also fails with MySQL Connection error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what was wrong. I'm used the query to call the stored procedure. Using the `cursor.callproc("sp_sensors_overview")` instead fixed my issue, and now I'm able to create the next cursor without errors.